# AngularJS Orderby

Tags: angularjs

I've got some tabular data in angularjs I'm sorting with standard sort funtions.  I want to know how to get the rows of a table that contain a certain value to show up first.

```
Item   Category1   Category2
```

The `Item` field is always unique, but there are multiple items that have the same value for `Category1`.

Is there a way I can use a custom `orderBy` function to get all the items that have a certain `Category1` value to show up first?

Comment: [The orderBy filter's](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) expression can be a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list all entries with a specific value first, just check for that value in your sort function and return a lower number for items with that value than other items. eg.

```
$scope.showValueFirst = function(item) {
    return item.Category1 == 'matched value' ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ngRepeat="item in items | orderBy:sortByCategory"
```

You could write a function like:

```
$scope.sortByCategory = function(item){
    return (item.category1 < item.category2);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$scope.sortByCategory = function(item) ...`?